# image logo not redirecting to another page

Tags: html, css

I gave my logo inside an a tag......
but when i click the logo its not redirecting to another page....
only when i click the bottom of the logo its redirecting....
how to make the logo to redirect to another page....... 
providing my code below...

http://jsfiddle.net/KNPZB/10/embedded/result/

```
.navbar .brand {
float: left;
display: block;
padding: 8px 20px 12px;
margin-left: -20px;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 200;
line-height: 1;
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have the `<div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">` over the logo.

Add

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
```

to the `.navbar .brand {}`

Comment: Your nav was overlapping the logo.

Comment: how did u find it out...i was not able to guess it

Comment: I'm a freelance web developer so that is experience. I removed `float:left` from your logo and then the logo was clickable. So I understood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `height` attribute to the actual height of the image.